# Attempting to set up static HTML pages using express

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to set up a few pages so that when a user goes to locahost:number/war . They can see the /war page. But when I run the server I get a "Cannot GET war" error on the page. I've set it up similar to this before and didnt have an issue.

I also get a "ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined" issue on the console

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
import path from 'path';
import {getData} from './server.js'

// HTML Routes

router.get('/', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../start.html"));
})
router.get('/war', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));
})
router.get('/score', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../finalScore.html"));
})

// Data
export async function sendStats(){
app.get("/data", (req,res)=> {
    const data = getData()
    res.json(data)
})
app.post("/data",(req, res) => {
    const {name, score} = req.body
    const data = createData(name, score)
    res.json(data)
} )
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send('Something Broke!')
})
app.listen(7171, ()=> {
    console.log('Server is running on port 9191')
})
}
const data = await sendStats();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the router in the app:

```
app.use('/', router)
```